# Help with a D7 database query and update

Tags: 7, database

I am not familiar with the Drupal 7 database API. I want to alphabetized a menu.
Can anyone help me write a database query to retrieve all the menu item links of a certain parent (plid = 228) and order ascending by title? Within that result set, can anyone help me write a database update method to update each menu item's weight sequentially (counter starts at 0 and increments)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work, but I have not tested this code. Please comment on this if you have questions.

```
$result = db_select('menu_links', 'ml') 
  ->fields('ml', 'mlid')
  ->condition('ml.plid', $plid, '=')
  ->orderBy('ml.link_title')
  ->execute();

$i=0;
foreach ($result as $row) {
  db_update('menu_links')
    ->fields(array('weight' => $i))
    ->condition('mlid', $row->mlid)
    ->execute();
  $i++;
}
```

At this point they would all be ordered by title, and you could print the menu wherever needed.